# Установка библиотеки Python на машине с windows с ограниченными правами

Tags: python, pip

На работе понадобилось иметь возможность работать с python с библиотекой pymssql. Из-за ограниченных прав при установке с помощью pip возникает следующая ошибка:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build...'

запуск с ключом --user дает туже ошибку.
какие права необходимо получить или как установить библиотеку без pip?

Comment: Используйте [виртуальные окружения](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Запустите консоль от имени администратора
2. Установите virtual venv

```html
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate 
python -m pip install pymssql
```

Пример взят под Linux.

Comment: создал env в корне диска "d. (env) d:\> python -m pip install pymssql.tar.gz" та же самая ошибка Errno 13